# How to reduce base64 image data and save to another varible?

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing browser crash while sending base64 image data from one HTML page to another HTML page. So, I want to reduce this base64 string and store it to another variable and then I want to pass that variable.

So how do I reduce base64 image data in JavaScript?

Comment: _"while sending base64 image data from one html page to another html "_ ? How do you do that ?

Comment: `reduce this base64 string` - what do you mean? make it smaller?

Comment: try using `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`

Comment: now i am sending "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkK" through URL from one html page to other html page.... I want to send it as a varible through javascript

Comment: @Bikshus by url you mean a `GET` query string?

Comment: yes..Like this..window.location.href='canvas4.html#id='+a+'&src='+base64stirng;

Comment: if you're going to do it that way use encodeURIcomponent(base64stirng) then grab the query var base64string = decodeURIcomponent(getParameterByName('src')) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks @Jaromanda X  I have achieved this with sessionStorage.setItem(); and sessionStorage.getItem();

Answer (score 0):

To reduce a string you should reduce the image itself. If you cannot control size of images (for example, if it is an image which is uploaded by the user) then you should consider another way to send images.

For example, you can use POST instead of GET (query string). Either use `<form>` tag or post via javascript (example: [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)).

Comment: Thanks Guys, I had achieved this through html5 session storage thanks lot.